# Count of most time consuming queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to take count of most time consuming queries for particular database in SQL Server

For ex :
Count of queries where time is between 30 to 45 min,
Count of queries where time is between 45 to 60 min,
Count of queries where time is greater than 60 min.

Answer (score 0):

There's a DMV for that, [sys.dm_exec_query_stats (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql). For example:

> Finding the TOP N queries
>
> The following example returns information about the top five queries ranked by average CPU time. This example aggregates the queries according to their query hash so that logically equivalent queries are grouped by their cumulative resource consumption.

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 query_stats.query_hash AS "Query Hash",   
    SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS "Avg CPU Time",  
    MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS "Statement Text"  
FROM   
    (SELECT QS.*,   
    SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,  
    ((CASE statement_end_offset   
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)  
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END   
            - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text  
     FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS  
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats  
GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash  
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Your specific question is asking about the `execution_count` column but, as seen above, there's much useful information to be found.